# Would there be any alternatives to a Logistic Regression or way to modify the Regression for what I'm looking for?

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, binary-data, nonlinear-regression

To provide more information I am looking for an alternative to logistic Regression or a way to modify it. This is because of two reasons:

- My data is widely dispersed across the X axis for both my 1s and 0s however there is slightly more 1s the higher the X and slightly more 0s the lower the X. So the probabilities listed in a standard Logistic regression I feel are over/understated on both ends of the X axis.
- I'm not very concerned with classifying future outcomes accurately, I'm more concerned in how movement along the X increases the probability for my 1 outcomes.

My main concern with a Logistic Regression is that the starting off point the probability of a 1 is close to 0% while the ending point the probability is 100% (given a positive relationship with the x).

With my data this isn't accurate as the probability of a 1 outcome would never hit 100%. I am wondering if there would a better method for me to utilize that would allow me to map out the relationship between my X variable against my 1 and 0 Y variables? Or a way to modify the regression to take into account that for my max X variable I will never have a 100% probability of getting a 1?

Basically I'm interested in knowing what my probability of a 1 outcome is for my max X while getting an accurate representation of how the probability will change with movement across my X axis.

Edit: Picture for example of a Logistic Regression (Not a picture of my actual data though)

[image: Picture for example of a Logistic Regression (Not a picture of my actual data though)]

Comment: Try plotting this with confidence or prediction intervals and see if that eases your concerns. Also, it would help if you could add a plot of your actual data, so we could see exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I am not seeing the problem with logistic regression yet - maybe you underestimate it's flexibility. Does it have to be a parametric model or will lowess do?

Comment: But does the logistic regression run over your data actually predict the probabilities like 100%? That would be the case if you have no negative examples in your data for such cases--so from the data point of view, it is a reasonable answer. If you want to constrain it, you can always do arbitrary things like "rounding down" the probabilities to arbitrary values--it doesn't have much sense, but it illustrates the arbitrariness of such solutions. Better alternative is a Bayesian model, but do you have enough prior knowledge to decide on informative priors?

Comment: "My main concern with a Logistic Regression is that the starting off point the probability of a 1 is close to 0% while the ending point the probability is 100% (given a positive relationship with the x)." - this is not a true statement about logistic regression.

Comment: *"the starting off point the probability of a 1 is close to 0% while the ending point the probability is 100%"* That fact that this is false, that is already shown in your image. The end points are close but not exactly equal to 0% and 100%.

Answer (score 5):

1. The probability will not hit 0% or 100% exactly, it approaches them asymptotically.
2. The uncertainty increases towards the extremes, which you will see if you include confidence intervals in your plot.

For these reasons, this is probably less of a problem than you think. But to answer your question: yes, there are alternatives to logistic regression. [Probit regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20523/121522) is one, though it may actually be worse given your concerns, because the curve will approach the extremes more rapidly than with the logistic. [GAMs can be used for binary data too](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30861/121522). And even simpler, you can just [use a moving-window mean](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/108077/121522).

Comment: A moving window mean typically performs less well than a logistic regression in a spline of X.

Answer (score 1):

> My data is widely dispersed across the X axis for both my 1s and 0s
> however there is slightly more 1s the higher the X and slightly more
> 0s the lower the X. So the probabilities listed in a standard Logistic
> regression I feel are over/understated on both ends of the X axis.

I feel you have misunderstood logistic regression.  The model is fit to your data, so if at extremes of your training data you don't approach 0/100% in the raw data, then you won't with logistic regression either. But clearly if your training data is between +/-1 there will be some range *outside* your data set where you approach 0/100%, maybe its at +/-10, maybe its at +/-100...